# Use next if positive number in while loop

Tags: r, loops

When generating normal random numbers with a while-loop I try to use next if the number is positive (and at the same time breaks if the number is smaller than -1). This is my attempt, but it does not work and still prints numbers larger than 0

```
  Random_numbers <- rnorm(1) 
  print(Random_numbers)

  while (Random_numbers > -1) {
  Random_numbers <- rnorm(1) 
  print(Random_numbers) 
    if (Random_numbers>0) next
  }
```

Comment: Put the `if` before the `print`.

Comment: I don't think I follow. Could you give a couple of samples of the desired output? And are you trying to figure out specifically how the `while` function works or are you just interested in getting that output?

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear - I need to need to modify this code (I have to use the while-loop) to generate random numbers neither below -1 or above 0. I hope this helps

Comment: @SteveM Thank you, I tried putting the if before print, but it still prints out positive numbers

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. When do you want to print number? When do you want to break the loop and not print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this vectorized approach:

```r
x <- rnorm(100)
x <- x[x >= 0]
```

This would generate roughly 50 random numbers evenly distributed which are positive.

Or you could just use:

```r
x <- abs(rnorm(100))   # for 100 random uniformly distributed numbers
```

Comment: `it has to be done with a while loop` ... Not true at all.  Even if this an assignment, you should never use a while loop in this way.